# Rails Association between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to find the association between some of my models.

User wants to select dishes for a week through current week's menu, menu is going to have dishes for each week. but a dish can belong to multiple menus, so it doesnt make sense to add belongs_to: menu.

```
User
has_many: selections
```

```
Menu
start_date
end_date
has_many: dishes
```

```
Dish
has_many: menus
```

```
Selection
has_many: dishes through: menu
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a many-to-many relationship here. Each Menu can have multiple Dishes and each Dish can belongs to multiple menus. So, you need a bridge table here, Let's say 'menu_items'. Now the structure would be something like this.

```
User [name, email, etc]
has_many: selections
has_many: menu_items, thorugh: selections
has_many: dishes, through: menu_items

Menu [start_data, end_date]
has_many: menu_items
has_many: dishes, through: menu_items

Dish [name]
has_many: menu_items
has_many: menus, through: menu_items

MenuItem [menu_id, dish_id]
belongs_to: menu
belongs_to: dish

Selection [menu_item_id, user_id]
belongs_to: user
belongs_to: menu_item
```

I suggest you go through the documentation to better understand the logic behind all this:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html